# Not able to resolve error message " Expected "(" but got identifier "tripduration" at [4:16]" in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Here's my code:

```
SELECT usertype,
CONCAT(start_station_name,"to",end_station_name),
COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
ROUND(AVG(CAST tripduration AS int64/60,2)) AS Newduration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY start_station_name,end_station_name,usertype
ORDER BY num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I will flag this question to be closed because error is clear and u need parenthesis where error says u need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

you missed () around `CAST`

```sql
SELECT usertype,
CONCAT(start_station_name,"to",end_station_name),
COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
ROUND(AVG(CAST (tripduration AS int64)/60),2) AS Newduration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY start_station_name,end_station_name,usertype
ORDER BY num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```